# Pose automatically mirrors

Tags: rigging, mirror

Whenever i try to pose my model, it automatically mirrors the pose on the x-axis. Fx whenever i try to lift the right leg, the left leg does the same. How do I get rid of that? I'm using Blender v2.72.
Thankyou!

Comment: Are you in Pose Mode? With an armature in edit mode there is an option for x-axis mirror. Bone constraints or drivers should be the only thing to cause a mirror effect while in pose mode.

Comment: Pls upload and give link to your blend file to for inspection, you can use http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a mirror modifier.  If you apply the mirror modifier and then reparent with automatic weights, that will fix the problem.  I do not know if there is a way to keep the mirror modifier and prevent this problem.